# Compression using LZ4Net

Tags: c#, compression, lz4

I'm trying to compress multiple files with lz4net, but I don't even know how to begin.

I have `string[]` or `List<string>` with filepaths (and relative paths) and want to compress it with lz4 to one file.

Later I want to decompress it with taking care about the relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [LZ4 dll](https://lz4net.codeplex.com/).

Create a buffer for each file:

```
public byte[] FileToByteArray(string fileName)
{
    byte[] buff = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
    buff = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
    return buff;
}
```

Then, use the buffers to commpress/decompress like this:

```
LZ4.LZ4Codec.Decode(input, offset, inputLength, outputLength); // Decoder
LZ4.LZ4Codec.Encode(input, offset, inputLength); // Encoder
```

If you are looking, [here is the full version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IonKiwi.lz4.net/1.0.5) of the LZ4 dll (includes frames compression).