# How to compress directory using LZ4Net

Tags: c#, compression, lz4

I need to compress a directory and its sub directories and files. First I tried with the native `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` but its slow. So I found LZ4 is the fast compression algorithm also found c# port `lz4net`. But I can't hardly find any tutorials for compress and decompress using `lz4net`.
[Compression using LZ4Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627462/compression-using-lz4net) (This is the only useful one I found on SO)
So how can I compress a directory using `lz4net`?

Comment: Why not use SharpZipLib. Binaries available here https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/. Code samples available here https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain I already mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal In the doc I found that it uses both stored and deflate compression methods. I don't think compression and decompression speed of deflate method is not good enough.

Comment: @Rebornx, What have you tried so far? Paste some code please.